# Finding the Roots of this Cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I need to find the roots of the cubic $x^3+19x^2-109x-2,431=0$ in order to continue on finding the roots of a Quartic.

But here, I am stuck. I don't really know any good ways to find the roots of any cubic with integer solutions.

Trying Cardano's Method gave me something completely different than what Desmos is telling me. The roots are supposedly $11,-13, -17$. So I'm wondering if it's possible to find the solutions to any cubic without knowledge on the value of the roots.

Comment: Have you tried the [Rational Roots Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?

Comment: If you guess that the roots are integers, then you could factor $2431 = 11 * 13 * 17$ and guessed from there (you know that two roots are negative, and that the sum of the roots is -19).

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm discouraged from  using the Rational Roots Theorem because of the large number $2,431$ and how it can be factored multiple ways. My goal is to solve for $x$ in the least amount of time possible.

Comment: Well, it does get you there on the first few tries. Since the leading coefficient is $1$ and there are only $3$ prime factors of $2431$, there really aren't that many possibilities to test.

Comment: "it can be factored multiple ways": $2431$ factors in exactly one way, with three factors.

Comment: I did not see that.. I thought it would have many factors, due to it being such a large number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ross Millikan answered, you probably made a mistake in your calculations using Cardano's method.

Let us do it exactly as the method is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

$$\Delta = 18abcd - 4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2$$ Using $a=1$, $b=19$, $c=-109$, $d=-2431$, this gives $\Delta =7225344$ and so, three real roots.

$$\Delta_0 = b^2 - 3ac=688$$

$$\Delta_1 = 2b^3 -  9abc + 27a^2d=-33280$$
$$\Delta_1^2-4 \Delta_0^3= -195084288$$
$$\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4 \Delta_0^3}=8064 i \sqrt{3}$$
$$C = \sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1 \pm \sqrt{{\Delta_1}^2 - 4 {\Delta_0}^3}}2}=4 \left(4\pm3 i \sqrt{3}\right)$$
One of the roots is given by
$$x = - \frac{1}{3a}\left(b+C+\frac{\Delta_0}{C}\right)$$ Using $C=4 \left(4+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)$, this gives $$x=-\frac{1}{3} \left(19+\frac{172}{4+3 i \sqrt{3}}+4 \left(4+3 i
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)=-17$$

Factoring let us with
$$x^3+19x^2-109x-2431=(x+17)(x^2+2 x-143)=0$$ and the quadratic is easy to solve for the other roots $(x=11,x=-13)$.

Comment: +1 for the demonstration of the technique. I do disagree with the assertion that the OP *must* have made a mistake however. The point I try to make in my answer is that he might have done it correctly but failed to recognize the numbers.It's just not clear from the information given in the question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure. Thanks for the appreciation and thenks for pointing the bad wording. I edited a little to make it less rude. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I used the other method... The one where you get a depressed cubic, and set that equal to $u+v$...

Comment: @Frank. This is fine too. I just wanted to illustrate the first as explained in Wikipedia. Did you go into any problem ? Why don't you add in to the post ? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As you've observed, the roots are 11, −13, and −17 and they can be found in several ways. Cardano's method works as well but might produce results that *appear* complicated. Using my own implementation of Cardano's method in Mathematica, I find the roots to be:

\begin{align}
x_1 &=-\frac{19}{3}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{16640}{27}-\frac{448
   i}{\sqrt{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{16640}{27}+\frac{448
   i}{\sqrt{3}}} \\
x_2 &= -\frac{19}{3}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{16640}{27}+\frac{448
   i}{\sqrt{3}}} \left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+\sqrt[3]{\frac{16640}{27}-\frac{448
   i}{\sqrt{3}}} \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \\
x_3 &= -\frac{19}{3}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{16640}{27}-\frac{448
   i}{\sqrt{3}}} \left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+\sqrt[3]{\frac{16640}{27}+\frac{448
   i}{\sqrt{3}}} \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
\end{align}

While it might not look like it at first glance, these happen to be 11, −13, and −17 in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

The roots you quote are correct per Alpha. Cardano's method will find the roots without prior knowledge, so you must have made a mistake. This will also yield to the rational root theorem.